# Server Not Starting with Uvicorn Command on Open Devin installation

Tags: uvicorn

I was trying to run the backend server with the OpenDevin installation, however, every time I tried to use `uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000` it said uvicorn is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.Then when I used `python -m uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000`it showed TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'. How do I start up the port on the backend?

I tried to use 'python -m uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000' to start the port through OpenDevin, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running the first command in the python environment you created during the set up.